# How to sync dmPages and dmWidgets across many Diem installs?

Tags: symfony, symfony-1.4, diem-cms

Diem is great CMS but it lacks the ability to sync pages (and widgets) across mirror sites.

I'm lead developer of middle-sized site that uses Diem-based CMS.

It would be great if we (group of about 50 people, not all of them developers, most of them not) could prepare major content changes/updates on a non-public mirror of our site and then push them to production at once.

I've been thinking about a way to synchronize dmPages across many installs (with the same db schema off course). I saw 2 problems:

- how to populate links (page:, media:) to make sure they would work after sync in new install
- how to transfer and populate widget assets.

I figured out such workflow using (nonexistant so far) import-export script:

1. export form development install **D** selected dmPages, dmWidgets (and if applicable: widget assets and belonging custom model entities and it's assets) to tarball archive (and possibly compress it)
2. import archive into production install **P**, uncompress and unarchive and process it

   1. analyze if there are any assets connected to widgets/model entities, copy it to appropriate web subfolder then create dmMedia and store its' IDs
   2. analyze if there are any model entities, create it, get and store IDs
   3. analyze if there are any widgets:

      - in *model*/show pages there's only one widget to create: show widget of model. Create it, store, get ID.
      - in non-model pages there can be many widgets. Create them (if applicable connects dmMedia created in 2.1), store IDs
   4. create dmPages, connect previously created dmWidgets
   5. analyze (only those imported ones!) widgets and model entities for the presence of *page:* or *media:* strings (so far from development install) **and change them to match IDs** in production install

Is there any solution what imports/exports dmPages so far? If not - do you have any suggestions to proposed workflow of my solution?